# Ruby youtube-dl.rb error caused by KeyError('Ai',)

Tags: ruby, youtube-dl

I've been using a gem called [youtube-dl.rb](https://github.com/layer8x/youtube-dl.rb), it works really great but some days ago it gave me an error and i haven't been able to fix it.

This is a sample code I used to test the gem after it kept giving me errors:

```
require 'youtube-dl.rb'
options_mp3 = {
    extract_audio: true,
    audio_format: "mp3",    
    output: '%(title)s.%(ext)s'
}
YoutubeDL.download "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqUZn0gWLk4", options_mp3
```

And this is the error I get:

```
D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocaine-0.5.8/lib/cocaine/command_line.rb:91:in `run': Command 'D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/youtube-dl.rb-0.3.1.2016.09.11.1/vendor/bin/youtube-dl --output "some_file.mp3" --no-color --no-progress --print-json "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqUZn0gWLk4"' returned 1. Expected 0 (Cocaine::ExitStatusError)
Here is the command output: STDOUT:
STDERR:
ERROR: Signature extraction failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpj47q005f\build\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 1005, in  _decrypt_signature
File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpj47q005f\build\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 932, in _extract_signature_function
File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpj47q005f\build\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 984, in <lambda>
File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpj47q005f\build\youtube_dl\jsinterp.py", line 254, in resf
File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpj47q005f\build\youtube_dl\jsinterp.py", line 55, in interpret_statement
File "C:\Users\dst\AppData\Roaming\Build archive\youtube-dl\rg3\tmpj47q005f\build\youtube_dl\jsinterp.py", line 174, in interpret_expression
KeyError: 'Ai'
(caused by KeyError('Ai',)); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
    from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/youtube-dl.rb-0.3.1.2016.09.11.1/lib/youtube-dl/runner.rb:62:in `run'
    from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/youtube-dl.rb-0.3.1.2016.09.11.1/lib/youtube-dl/video.rb:39:in `download'
    from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/youtube-dl.rb-0.3.1.2016.09.11.1/lib/youtube-dl/video.rb:15:in `download'
    from D:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/youtube-dl.rb-0.3.1.2016.09.11.1/lib/youtube-dl.rb:25:in `download'
    from test.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

Whenever I used the example youtube link on the github site it doesn't give me an error and downloads the video in mp4

```
YoutubeDL.download "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvdf5n-zI14", output: 'some_file.mp4'
```

Someone has any idea how to fix this? If not, any suggestion on downloading youtube videos a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On January 10th 2017, YouTube changed their player in a way that broke youtube-dl. Consequently, youtube-dl has been [updated](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/commit/d1aeacd9bfe12bdf064d8888f77ccf8bd30f1723). Please make sure that you are using youtube-dl 2017.01.10 or newer. Have a look at the [updating instructions](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl) on how to update youtube-dl.

Comment: That would make sense that the older video worked and the newer ones didn't. Instead of this gem i use the original youtube-dl and i use the "system" command now and it works fine, just had to edit my code a bit.

Comment: It's less about video age, but video class. Music (and some commercial) videos use a different YouTube player. By thew way, if this (or any other) answer solves, feel free to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). Thanks!